# Responsive table columns and rows (only CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

this is my situation:

I have a **3x2** html table with a 100% width.

```
| CELL A1 | CELL A2 | CELL A3 | 
------------------------------- 
| CELL B1 | CELL B2 | CELL B3 |
```

Every cell has a min-width (ex. 300px).

So what i want to do is: when resizing under 900px a cell should shift to the next row (instead of creating scroll), and table will become **2x3** like this (whithout necessarily  changing original table structure):

```
| CELL A1 | CELL A2 |
---------------------
| CELL A3 | CELL B1 |
---------------------
| CELL B2 | CELL B3 |
```

Constraints: this HAS TO BE a table, not divs.

Best solution would be using mostly CSS and avoiding as much as possible javascript/jquery manipulation.. how can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot achieve this with table and no javascript.  If a table is defined as having 3 columns, it will have 3 columns no matter what.  With javascript, you can catch the resize event, check the sizes and remove/re-add cells in the table.  I'm not sure why you can't have divs - it would be so much easier.

Comment: SO is for asking specific problems not being handed solutions without any approach being made

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The approach i was going to take was javascript manipulation.. i was just wondering if there was a tricky way to do it in css, not necessarily modifying table structure (it can still be a 3x2 table) but simulating the div behaviour. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fwdio (tested on latest Firefox and Chrome)

---

**CSS**

```
table{
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  display: inline;
}

td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: #d8d8d8;
} 

/* revert/restore properties on larger screen */
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
  tr {
    display: table-row;
  }
  td {
    float: none;
    min-width: 300px;
  } 
}
```

Basically the idea is to change the display property of your table rows to `inline` and float the cells on a viewport narrower than `900px`

Answer (score 0):

If it is Static table then here is the easy solution.

Create two division with these two different kind of table. Initially hide the three row table. Check the width using media query and make the three row division visible and hide the two row division.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with plain HTML, whatever written in HTML it will be there!

If you want an easy method check out bootstrap, but it is kinda heavy for your liking

http://getbootstrap.com/

Bootstrap, takes care of all the resizing of the table for you and it is very simple to use.

If, you want to do it yourself without Bootstrap,
this is the logic, but you have to write the code yourself.

i) constantly check for resizing of window size

ii) put your resize condition, if met redraw the table again

It is not possible to use just plain CSS and HTML, you need javascript to catch the event

Answer (score -1):

CSS can not solve this problem.

you can use jquery/Javascript solutions.

solution:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    tds=new Array();
    $("table td").each(function(){
        tds.push('<td>'+$(this).html()+'</td>');
    });
    newtable='';
    for(i=0;i<tds.length;i+=2){
        newtable+='<tr>'+tds[i]+tds[i+1]+'</tr>';
    }
    $('table').html(newtable);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dk3JM/1/